# Applying math rules (like rnd, max etc) to value entered by user using AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have sum calculation rules defined as below, where 2013 represents the year and 5 and 6 are some codes sent over to the program:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.MATHRULES = {
        2013: {
            5: 'min(1123, 106800)', 
            6: 'min(Math.max(Math.round(123123 * 0.062)), 0)'            
        }
    };
});
```

Question:
I want to write a directive where I can apply the rules mentioned above based on the year and code coming in from attrs, only when the user enters some new values. Please let me know how to do that. Should I use a scope.$watch or something to see if the value changes?

```
app.directive('wuiMathRules', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a watch to the link function. It can watch a scope variable which could be the model of the input field the user updates.